# Questions regarding BJT saturation for a circuit

Tags: bjt, saturation

I have the following circuit which converts weak sine signal to pulses:

[image]

I have tried it on breadboard and it seems it works fine. In my application freq. is between 1Hz to 30Hz or max 100Hz. And the input signal Vpp will be from 200mV to 2Vpp.

Below is the collector and base currents:

[image]

And here below graph zoomed to show Vce which is 50mV during saturation:

[image]

**Here are my questions:**

**1)** I'm not sure if R2 and R3 is set correct/optimum for using this circuit for switching action even though in practice it works(I set R2 and R3 empirically). Am I oversaturating this transistor? In my second plot above Ic/Ib<10 but in its [data sheet](http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/308/BC547-1118654.pdf) at saturation Ic/Ib should be around 10. It is a bit confusing.

Briefly I want to learn how can we calculate R2 and R3 for good saturation and what should be their rough value?

**2)** All the texts I have seen says Vce is around 0.2 during BJT's saturation but in my simulation(3rd plot) it is only 50mV. Why is that so?

Comment: Before answering I and surely the others, too, want to know what is the intended usage of the generated pulses. No optimization is possible without knowing it. Your generated pulses for example have quite slow ramps for many applications that need pulses which change their state in nanoseconds.

Comment: Freq will be between 1Hz to 30Hz. And fast rising edges are not important since this will pull down an NPN input of another device which will take care of it. Precision is not important.

Comment: It is saturating better than Vce(sat)@ ? mA because you are using less current than ? mA. Imagine an internal collector R, we call Rce and then you can estimate Vce(sat)

Comment: @user134429 Is this just turning a sine wave into a square wave with perhaps hysteresis? And you really are using a \$14.2\:\textrm{V}\$ power supply? And this is driving yet another NPN circuit? I wouldn't recommend a single CE stage for this, but you say it drives another NPN circuit anyway, so it seems as though you should disclose the 2nd stage so that one might attempt to merge their functions. But up to you. Other than that, it's not clear to me what isn't clear to you. Asking "am I oversaturating" just leaves me wondering without really clarifying your quandary, for example. (To me.)

Comment: @jonk It will drive the NPN input of this: https://brodersencontrols.com/images/pxf-20_11.pdf 14.2V is the supply from this device(I guess this device will sharpen pulses as well). I could use another supply for the transistor as well. Regarding my circuit, the input range will be 200mVpp to 2Vpp. I checked in real this circuit works but I'm not sure R2 and R3 is set correct/optimum values. If Ic/Ib<10 does that mean something is wrong? Or is there a limit for Ib? How would you set R3 and R2 for the input range I mentioned?

Comment: 200 mV is a rule of thumb figure for hard switching a device near its rated Ic. For lower currents vce sat will be lower

Comment: @sstobbe hard switching means almost switching?  For lower currents Vce will be  lower?? In linear region currents are lower but Vce is higher. I didnt get what you mean.

Comment: Your datasheet is somewhat sparse, but take for example this 2n3904 datasheet http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/149/2N3904-82270.pdf take a look at fig 2 vce sat vs Ic. Note it's actually also in your datasheet as Fig4

Comment: How would you set up R2 and R3 for proper saturation for input range between 200mVpp to 2Vpp sine? What is the reasoning methodology  behind? Is there a method or calculation way?

Comment: R2 and R3 don't provide the base current for saturation. In your implementation the base current driving q1 into saturation is sourced from your signal source.

Comment: I would personally study this as a CE amp, as I suspect you also care how close the output gets pulled to VCc when the output is high

Comment: I noticed my max input can be 12Vpp

Comment: An opamp or lm339 comparator with series R and protection diodes would be a more practical approach

Comment: I opened a new question with the new circuit with a comparator: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/327019/questions-on-interfacing-circuit-for-an-npn-input

Comment: While we're discussing the circuit in general, I question the need for C2, or at least the specific value.  In this simulation it does nothing except attenuate the input signal a small amount.  In the real world it will provide some high frequency filtering, but this will depend on the impedance of the signal source.

Answer (score 1):

It is difficult to make a single transistor work as a limiter unless there are limits on input signal range and frequency, so you need to define these limits.

But assuming they are only for the values given, we can make it better.

When your input signal goes low Vbe turns off and the collect current shuts off and Vc is pulled up according the Rc value and ratios.

When your input goes high , collector goes low but it stays low more than half the time so the input is pulled up too much from negative feedback current.

### Solution?

1) Change bias of R2 from 0V to Vcc but with a value of 10x Rc or roughly 20k

- Why? Vce(sat) is normally rated at Ic/Ib=10

2) Change R3 from 20x Rc to 50x Rc or ~ 100K
Change Rf

When Vce saturates , its voltage Vce(sat) depends on the collector current as if there was a small series R, which we can call "Rce". This value controls the Vce(sat) and Rce is reduces as device power rating increases. Then it is affected by temperature and chip design so the default spec is Vce(sat) at some rated current.  Rce is similar to RdsOn in MOSFETs but not as low. You may estimate this as the rise of Vce(sat) for rise in current as long as base current is at least 5~10% of collector.

### p.s.

Normally 2 devices working in differential mode give a better result then we move up to comparator designs or use a CMOS logic buffered inverter AC Coupled with high R feedback for self biasing for amazing simplicity. with large R values and much small C coupling values. like 10M and 0.1uF

Comment: I made a minor mistake I updated my circuit now. R3 would be directly connected to Vcc.  Are you saying R2 better 20k and R3 100k? In my application freq. is between 1Hz to 30Hz or max 100Hz. And the input signal Vpp will be from 200mV to 2Vpp.

Comment: Input is not fixed. Range is 200mV to 2Vpp. Following your logic, I set R3 to 220k and R2 to 39k; to make things better for the 200mVpp to 2Vpp input range. Do you think makes sense?

Comment: 2V is driving too much current into Vbe , what is source impedance?  WIth that range you need a better limiter than 1 or 2 transistors, BTW the F2V converter is overkill.

Comment: I noticed my max input can be 12Vpp

Comment: this is the sensor I want to use https://www.nrgsystems.com/assets/resources/an40C-IF3-interface.pdf together with F2V converter's NPN input

Comment: why have you ignored the advice with  given solution in the datasheet?   Clamp diodes, hysteresis and logic level out. Instead to tried to use the F2V convert with the NPN option

Comment: F2V is not my idea, i just have to use it with NPN input its a directive. I could use a comparator instead of my BJT circuit but I guess F2V already takes care of rsng edges. Now my only concern is how to clamp voltages in my circuit. Do you think rail to rail diodes before the base would do the job? Or 5V back to back zener?

Comment: Does it have to comply with all the automotive directives like reverse voltage and surge dump too?  Sorry your specs are insufficient and questions too narrow.

Comment: Yes exactly I need those as well but as a first step I wanted to be sure about this circuit.

Comment: if you insist, I suggest you use the recommended circuit with a comparator that has an NPN output.  aka open collector. I'm done here,

Comment: I decided to follow your suggestion. I opened a new question with the new circuit: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/327019/questions-on-interfacing-circuit-for-an-npn-input

Comment: I am hesitant to help, because your specs are incomplete for the design to be immune to failure with environment, and automotive stress tests.  then  using a primitive Q pulse amp with a $200 V/F converter shows inexperience.  It could work, but what else can influence the signal? CM noise from spark plugs. get my drift? too many unknowns.

Comment: Is this going to be on a PCB in a car or out in the woods -40~+40'C, all makes a difference.  What is Vcc , is there an LDO or data collection Regulator? single supply only , shielded sensor floating or grounded, single ended or differential?

Comment: what is the min R load on anemometer ? Rbe? 100 ohm? 1k? 10k @ 100 Hz? load may affect RPM  what is DCR of sensor?