# Questions on interfacing circuit for an NPN input

Tags: analog, signal-processing, comparator, npn

I have to use [this](https://www.nrgsystems.com/assets/resources/an40C-IF3-interface.pdf) sinewave outputting sensor with the NPN input of this [converter](https://brodersencontrols.com/images/pxf-20_11.pdf). My [previous question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/326940/questions-regarding-bjt-saturation-for-a-circuit) was related to the same issue but the question was about a totally different circuit design i.e. a single CE amplifier. Even the circuit was working in practice, from many expert comments I was suggested to make an interface with a comparator instead and use voltage protection.

Input is a sensor which outputs sine waves from 200mVpp to 12Vpp between 1Hz upto 100Hz. The circuit below I aim to convert these sinusoidal inputs to pulses and via comparator's open collector I want to pull down NPN input (Y1) of the F2V converter. Output impedance of Y1 is not given so I measured it with different resistors as around 2k (R1 in the circuit).

[image]

In simulation I get the following voltage output at Y1:

[image]

It seems this works in simulation for the desired input ranges.

Is my way of driving this sensor to the converter correct? Can this circuit be optimized or improved? Are the locations of TVS and diodes correct? I'm just wondering if there is fundamental error before I start soldering.

edit:

[image: ![enter image description here]

Above is how I'm going to configure the setup. The points A, B, C and D are in question for protection. I was only thinking for the moment MOV or TVS for the point A.

**EDIT2:**

Corrected comparator circuit:
[image]

Suggested self powered transistor circuit:
[image]

I apply this noisy signal as an input to both:

[image]

With 100mV hysteresis the comparator circuit inputs:

[image]

Comparator circuit final output at Y1:

[image]

Transistor circuit's final output at Y1:

[image]

Comment: What is source impedance of Vin and is there any common mode noise?  Another way to clamp the input voltage is two back to front parallel diodes to clamp the Vpp to Vf with say 10K series R.  Then amplifying to trigger a non-retriggerable mode one shot ( dual IC) for 10ms  will give Vdd out at 100Hz and Vdd/10 at 10 Hz. This can be done in 1 or 2 IC's. Ensure reverse polarity protection to Vdd using 5V automotive LDO.

Comment: Is it important to you to have the output @ Y1 in a known state (either high or low) when your sensor is inactive, or disconnected? Your circuit now gives an undetermined output for this condition, depending on resistor tolerances of R21,R22, R23, R24.

Comment: Y2 isn't a voltage rail. It's a \$20\:\textrm{mA}\$ current source. Are you able to see that from the PXF-20 datasheet you linked?

Comment: @jonk Thanks if you say so I didnt get it right it says " Internal sensor supply 12,6V to 14V @ 0-20mA." When I measure Y2 with scope it shows 14.2V thats why I thought it can be used for power. So I have to use a separate power supply right? If I use a separate power supply for the circuit do I need to isolate it via optocoupler or it is ok this way?  I would be glad if you have any other inputs for this circuit and values. Especially my concern is for choosing a TVS for overvoltage protection since I will place the sensor in open air. Any of your input is precious thanks.

Comment: @user134429 If you look at their schematic, it's kind of sloppy but it basically shows you (on the right side) what their schematic is. On the left, they show you three kinds of inputs they can accept and how they would be wired. That part looks like a rats nest, messy. They could have shown three separate diagrams and it would have been clearer. They are supplying you with a \$20\:\textrm{mA}\$, if you want it. (Worth thinking about.) Or you can just ignore Y2 and give them a clean signal between Y1 and Y0.

Comment: @user134429 Regarding overvoltage, a wind speed device is out in the weather and open spaces and can be very easily be subject to lightning strikes. So you probably should consider some serious protection. Something like what a copper telephone line service provides. As well as, perhaps, some added opto isolation somewhere along the line, too. I might consider the use of a fiber optic line, even. But I don't know your weather circumstances, either. Up to you.

Comment: @user134429 The reason you measure about \$14.2\:\textrm{V}\$ is probably because they have a \$15\:\textrm{V}\$ internal voltage rail and are using a PNP BJT as part of a "current mirror" to provide the \$20\:\textrm{mA}\$. This would tend to mean about a diode drop from there to the voltage you'd measure, then. So it makes sense. The schematic shows it as a current source, so I'd trust in that much.

Comment: @user134429 Do you have your own voltage supply rail that has to be there anyway? Or would you prefer to use the PXF-20's \$20\:\textrm{mA}\$ source in order to self-power your wind speed anemometer circuit?

Comment: @jonk I can use external supply actually same 12VDC supply for F2V and the comparator circuit. Thanks for showing how make voltage source form 20mA output but I think I will go for the comparator circuit because it seems easier to set things. The sensor datasheet says use a 18V MOV at the input (where my TVS is) I guess at least it is better than nothing for over voltage protection right?

Comment: I edited the question and added how Im going to configure the setup. The points A, B, C and D are in question for protection. I was only thinking for the moment MOV or TVS for the point A.

Comment: I am concerned about how your entire system measures analog output without any EMC design and only overly-concerned about "protection"  Can you make a block diagram of entire system with cable shields grounds and potential,sources of interference.?

Comment: There is No galvanic isolation between input and analogue output. It would be far better (for immunity, integrity and simplicity) to send the tach voltage all the way to measurement system with opto isolation at far Rx end. I think @jonk would agree.  This is how we did wind sensors in '75. The anemometer is also a lightning rod that needs to be earthed. So this question and previous becomes irrelevant.

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 Yeah. I agree about the exposures any weather system experiences and the need for significant protection before the signal enters a home. I'd use fiber optics because I use it semi-regularly for phosphor thermometry and have the stuff and tools laying about here.

Comment: There is no current limiting R for TVS, does anemometer slow down when TVS acts as a load?

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 The resistance of the sensor's coil is 680 Ohm. In their suggested diagram for the input(MOV or TVS) I couldn't see any limiting resistor. https://www.nrgsystems.com/assets/resources/an40C-IF3-interface.pdf Do you really think that one leg of MOV or TVS in this diagram will be connected to the "Protection earth" but not the circuit's ground?

Comment: Suggested discrete design can be improved with hysteresis using 10M from Q5-C to Q3-b... motor electrical load will reduce RPM

Comment: Datasheet uses 100k load with 0.1uF  ...TVS is <1 ohm !!  pls use this with >> 1M comparator iput impedance not 5k

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 Yess u are right you added around 200mV hysteresis. What determines the hysteresis in that transistor circuit? Ie I would like to set it to 100mV.

Comment: then use 20M  it is a V divider of vout *Rin/Rf then use their input LPF for R6C3 and no need for a TVS or for discrete add 0.1uF after 100k

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 No need for TVS or MOV for the transistor circuit? And for the comparator circuit where should I place the TVS/MOV? right before the non inverting input? Was that what you meant?

Comment: with 100K 0.1uF LPF no need in either as C will absorb transient and current limited but consider 100k limited by breakdown voltage of R

Answer (score 1):

To be clear:

1. I don't have your PXF-20 that I might use to validate some assumptions I'm making. And its manual is somewhat "cloudy" to my reading of it.
2. It seems as though your anemometer, from its datasheet, just as a fat, two-axis, four-pole magnet spinning inside a 4100 turn #40 coil to generate the AC.
3. The AC voltages are larger when the anemometer is spinning faster (as would be expected); at the slower rates this can be as little as \$80\:\textrm{mV}_\textrm{PP}\$; at the higher rates this can be over \$12\:\textrm{V}_\textrm{PP}\$.
4. There's no indication in your writing (that I recall) which tells me that all you want to do is to hook up your anemometer to your PXF-20 so that it can output a nice, clean signal for you based only upon the frequency.

From these, I conclude that there is no particular reason to complicate what's needed by adding a separate power supply if it is possible to instead power the circuit directly from the PXF-20.

I think that's possible with a fairly simple circuit.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fHNltS.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The left side, including \$R_1\$, \$R_2\$, \$R_3\$, \$R_4\$, \$Q_1\$, and \$C_1\$ play two important roles here. Using \$Y_2\$ and \$Y_0\$ they provide \$\approx 12\:\textrm{V}\$ power supply for the rest of the circuit (which requires only a very small amount of current to operate.) The exact voltage of this power supply isn't critical. These parts also provide an output to \$Y_1\$, which is specified in your datasheet as providing hysteresis (important) with a band sitting between \$5\:\textrm{V}\$ and \$7.5\:\textrm{V}\$. Without any input from your anemometer, \$Y_1\$ will be sitting at about \$1\:\textrm{V}\$, well below the threshold.

Now, the right side is powered and when the anemometer generates even a small signal the remaining circuit will alternately release and then drive the Darlington pair, \$Q_4\$ and \$Q_5\$, allowing \$Y_1\$ to rise well above the \$7.5\:\textrm{V}\$ threshold and fall well below the \$5\:\textrm{V}\$ as the small AC signal continues. This will work with even a small AC input, but it will also work with the higher generated voltages, too.

I've picked high-\$\beta\$ NPN transistors here and I think it's worth the trouble to use them. (I didn't include it, but you might also include a \$680\:\textrm{k}\Omega\$ resistor from the base of \$Q_4\$ to \$Y_0\$.)

There is no lightning protection here! Just be aware.

---

I've made some assumptions that are possibly unwarranted about your anemometer. If I had it here, I could do some testing on it. But I don't. I'm guessing that the wire resistance alone is at least \$300\:\Omega\$ in the wound coil. I honestly don't actually know, though. But I think the circuit is worth a shot.

If you do decide to try it, first just build up the portion that includes  \$R_1\$, \$R_2\$, \$R_3\$, \$R_4\$, \$Q_1\$, and \$C_1\$. Then verify that there is something from about \$10\:\textrm{V}\$ to about \$12\:\textrm{V}\$ on the emitter of \$Q_1\$. You should also see about \$1\:\textrm{V}\$ less than that at \$Y_1\$. If that's working out about right, then you can consider adding the rest and seeing if that works okay.

Mostly, this is to help you consider the idea of a self-powered circuit and show you one of the simpler (but less accurate) ways to approach solving that problem when interfacing an anemometer like this. It takes advantage of the provided current source and provides signal conditioning sufficient perhaps to drive the \$Y_1\$ input, as well.

I'm a little more worried about the slower anemometer speeds because of the tiny AC voltages generated. If that's still a problem more can be done, of course. You might try and change the value of \$R_6\$ a bit, one way or another, and see how that adjusts things better. But you'd probably need an oscilloscope tied to \$Y_1\$ and grounded at \$Y_0\$ to know better, then.

---

By the way, if you want to try and simulate your permanent magnet anemometer you might look over "[Permanent Magnet Synchronous Machine Model for Real-Time Simulation](http://web.mit.edu/kirtley/kirtley/binlustuff/literature/electric%20machine/PM%20machine%20model%20for%20simulation.pdf)" to see what I had to play with in trying to make sure the circuit I provided had a shot at working. I was able to get a behavior that relatively closely mimics the specifications provided by the anemometer datasheet, where merely changing the rate also changes the voltage approximately in the way they said it did. But it was annoying to develop and it's non-trivial. But it gave me a little better confidence that the circuit might work well, too. Worth a moment's trouble.

Comment: Many thanks for the nice answer. You are right Y2 is a current source I verified it by connecting 220 Ohm resistor I read around 5V. But I dont know why they write 0-20mA instead of just 20mA is its a current source(?). Also what's the purpose of Y2 as current source, I would think better to provide a voltage source for one's gadget. I opened the sensor and it is like 4 pole magnet rotating and inducing voltage across the coil. So the coil resistance hence the sensor's resistance I measured as around 680 Ohm.

Comment: There will be 12V or 24V power supply anyway for PFX, so I was planning to use the same supply for my comparator circuit's power rails. Is your transistor circuit have enough hysteresis? Im a bit worried about overvoltage caused by weather lightning ect. Can I add TVS between sensor output and the circuit in your transistor circuit like in my circuit?

Comment: @user134429 My circuit doesn't have any hysteresis. Your PFX-20 has the hysteresis at the input \$Y_1\$. I think it would be wise to worry about lightning. But I'm not qualified to comment on providing good protection, either. I do know that it can be complicated, involving design elements of your structure and nearby areas ("rolling circles" design, for example) and also specific elements at the entry point into the home. This is why I said I might go with fiber optic cable at the home entry point. The resistance you measured seems reasonable, about twice the absolute minimum I estimated.

Comment: @user134429 The circuit can be simplified a little if you have your own power supply rail. But you'd need to make a FINAL decision about exactly how you want to arrange things. My own feeling is that you should concentrate on supplying the PFX-20 properly and just self-power the circuit itself from the 20 mA current source they provide. This isolates the two issues. And since the PFX-20 supplies the 20 mA whether you like it or not, might as well just use it.

Comment: With comparator circuit I can set hysteresis for noisy sinusoids like 100mV hysteresis. If this is not done at the beginning Y1 will not know that it was noise. I dont know if I could explain what in my mind. But one more question to you if you dont mind, in their datasheet for the wind sensor https://www.nrgsystems.com/assets/resources/an40C-IF3-interface.pdf I look at their suggested block diagram. The over voltage protection component's one leg is tied to "protection earth" not to the circuit's own ground. Is that really what is supposed to be Im really confused why it is like that. Thanks

Comment: @user134429 The PFX-20 explicitly says (page 2) that "NPN: High > 7,5V and Low < 5V." This tells you that the \$Y_1\$ input already has hysteresis thresholds set at those levels. That's \$2.5\:\textrm{V}\$ of hysteresis! Which is pretty good. They are ***already*** providing all the hysteresis you need. So stop worrying about that part. Yes, their earthed zener supposedly keeps the line near earth. But it's not lightning protection in my mind.

Comment: Im sorry but I dont agree. I will simulate both circuits and upload the results. You will see lack of hysteresis at the beginning will cause glitch at the F2V input which cannot be eliminated.

Comment: @user134429 I'll take your word that the PXF-20 (F2V?) doesn't have any hysteresis. I was just "interpreting" what I read, but I have no way of testing the idea. You have it and can test the idea. Use the \$Y_1\$ input (relative to \$Y_0\$) when performing the test, please. But if it isn't there, it isn't. And if not then, yes, it might be helpful to add hysteresis. (I did add a tiny bit of negative feedback to the circuit.)

Comment: Please see my edit2 I tried to demonstrate what I meant. See the 1-12V glitches. Thanks

Comment: @user134429 That demonstrates nothing much! You need to include the PXF-20, which is what I tentatively assert has the hysteresis! The circuit I provided isn't supposed to do that, as I said earlier. If you assert that the PXF-20 doesn't have any hysteresis, you'll have to do more than use Spice on my circuit. Also, I didn't use that "anemometer" input as a Spice model simulator!! You need to create a MUCH MORE complex circuit to do that (which I did, but didn't show you.) In short, you need two more components to your model: the PXF-20 and the anemometer. Those are non-trivial.

Comment: PXF-20 has hysteresis but only 2.5 volt. Glitch is 12V or im still missing a point

Comment: @user134429 Also, you have a voltage source at V1. What is that doing there??? Look, you really need to get the models right. I built a "pseudo PXF-20" that I did NOT show you. I also built an "anemometer" model I also did not show you. Neither of what I built looks like your schematic. I think we hold short for now on the discussion until we can agree about what to simulate and how -- if that's your sole goal. I'd rather see exact testing on the actual equipment. The circuit is simple enough. But I think we are far apart on how to simulate the input and how to simulate the PXF-20, too.

Comment: V1 is the voltage at Y1 when I measure it with a scope. But when I measured it with different resistances I calculated the output impedance of Y1 as 2k. So V1 and 2k is the model for Y1.

Comment: @user134429 I'm reading the datasheet. Y1 is an input. I don't see any reason to think your model is accurate. Perhaps you should contact the supplier of it. For now, we can both stare at the datasheet and both see different things. And I can't say I trust your interpretation, for now. So we leave this here. I appreciate your thoughts. But I simply can't yet agree with them and we are stuck on that point. However, that said it was still an interesting question and I did +1 it (and meant that.) I may actually play with these ideas sometime in the future, myself.

Comment: Alright I understand thanks for the suggestions (Y1 is written input but it is actually collector of NPN transistor hence it is powering NPN as in CE configuration)

Comment: @user134429 That's where we completely disagree! As I read the datasheet the NPN, PNP, and NAMUR boxes are ***external*** to the PXF-20. They are suggested connections should you be using when you use one of those three types of input devices, each of which are supported by the PXF-20. (But they are NOT a part of it.)

Comment: There is around 14.2VDC at Y1. NPN is not part of PFX but Y1 is the collector to the NPN we use. Y1 is not a 0-10V ect pulse input.